# ASP Script time out

Tags: asp-classic

I wonder if anyone can help with the problem you have .

This is when I 'm programming in classic asp and the charging time is too large jumps me the error that time script time out has been exceeded but can not find a way to capture this error so that it does not leave the user , I tried to resume on error, but nothing ...

Can anybody help me? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
server.scripttimeout = 300 'time in seconds
```

Be very careful, because any looping error will now lock one processor (only one if your server has more) for exactly 5 minutes!

I use this setting only for pages that have only 2 or 3 users. Otherwise you may want to break down your query in elements that run in milliseconds.